# Delete a schedule Job that execute a batch job after the batch is finish

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

We want to execute a schedule job after a change occurs in one of ours custom objects. The Idea is to execute a batch after 10 min with all the changes that occurred on that time period. For that we have implemented the following apex class:

```
lobal class ConnectUpdateBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful, Schedulable {
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ID, Id__c, Email__c FROM ConnectEmailPreferences__c]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<ConnectEmailPreferences__c> scope) {
    ConnectService.processRecords(scope);
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    AsyncApexJob a = [
        SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
        FROM AsyncApexJob
        WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()
    ];
    system.abortJob(a.id);
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    try {
        // Abort the job you have just scheduled via Setup
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :SC.getTriggerId()];
        if (ct != null) {
            System.abortJob(ct.Id);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('No jobs scheduled ' + e.getMessage());
    }
    ConnectUpdateBatch b = new ConnectUpdateBatch();
    database.executebatch(b);
}
```

}

Basically this will call an external system to enrich the custom Object that has been created.

We want to do this on demand, meaning, if a new record is inserted, we check if there is a schedule job or not. In the case where we don't have one, we schedule it to run on the next 10 min.

After the job is run, we want to delete the schedule that was created. For that, on the finish method above we are using:

```
system.abortJob(a.id)
```

The scheduled jobs is aborted but we see on the Apex Jobs two entries:

[image]

One about the Scheduled Apex that was aborted and another one about the Batch Apex. What we want is just to Abort the Scheduled Apex, not the Batch. How we can achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: remove the system.abortJob from the finish() as you are already aborting the scheduled job in the schedulable.execute()

Comment: That is what I was looking for @cropredy. Thanks